# How to map two array JSON to data in vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, vue.js

I have JSON data that have two different arrays in one sheet.
I want to show each Organization Page then each page have every comment from the user who selects comment this organization.

```
{
ListOrg: {
id: 1613,
name_org: "US company",
rating: 0,
},
Review: [
{
review_id: 3,
org_id: 1613,
user_id: 2,
description: "Very good",
rating: 3,
user: {
id: 2,
  name: "Kunjanaphorn",
  firstname: "Kunjanaphorn",
  lastname: "Boonmak",
  admin: 0,
  email: "Pim@gmail.com",
}
},
{
review_id: 4,
org_id: 1613,
user_id: 3,
description: "Not bad",
rating: 5,
user: {
  id: 3,
  name: "Kan",
  firstname: "Kan",
  lastname: "Tippayamontree",
  admin: 0,
  email: "First@gmail.com",
}
}
]
}
```

But I cannot map it to data in vue.js. I try this solution then it not work.

```
  data() {
    return {
      Listorgs: [],
      Reviews: [],
      Listorg: {
        name_org: "",
        picture: "",
        headerpic: "",
        description: ""
      }

  mounted() {
    axios.get("/api/listorgs/" + this.id).then(response => {
      var listorg = response.data;
      this.Reviews = listorg.Review;
      this.Listorgs = listorg.Listorg;
    });
  }
```

Can you tell me about syntax

I want some attribute in each array -> name_org(string) from array ListOrg, description(string) from array Review, name(string) and firstname(string) from user array in Review array for show in vue page

[image]

Comment: What kind of results are you getting now and what kind or result are you expecting?

Comment: I want some attribute in each array -> name_org(string) from array ListOrg, description(string) from array Review,  name(string) and firstname(string) from user array in Review array

Comment: Please add your template. I guess, you can add it with `v-for` directive. Display fields which you need to show.

Comment: @varit05 I tray to check with console.log(ListOrgs.length); but it shows 0

Comment: `ListOrgs` is object and object doesn't have `length` property. Which fields you want to display in the UI?

Comment: @varit05 I add display now

Comment: you have `Reviews` in your script and `reviews` in your HTML.

Comment: I already fix it but it not work @varit05

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190811/discussion-between-varit05-and-kunjanaphorn-boonmak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have helped you changed a little bit and made it work, check it out.

https://jsfiddle.net/fLvy3am9/

```
  var listorg = response.data;
  this.orgData = listorg.ListOrg;
  this.reviews = listorg.Review.map((review) => {
    return {
      name_org: listorg.ListOrg.name_org,
      description: review.description,
      user: review.user
  };
  });
```

Ask me if there's any question.

Comment: Thanks, it works but if I get JSON data with Axios. Can you tell me about syntax when getting response.data

Comment: Usually I would use `.then({ data } => ` to destructure the data attribute from response. Then access ListOrg using data.ListOrg